# combine multiple plots in one graph

Tags: r, pie-chart, boxplot

I would like to combine 2 pie charts and 2 box plots on one graph. What is the easy way to combine this? My code is shown below.

```
x <-  c(20, 12, 4, 16, 8)
y <- c(30, 12,45, 20, 9)
names <- c("germany","france","australia","vienna","hungary")
par(fig=c(0,0.5,0,1))
p1 <- pie(x, names, col = c("purple", "cyan", "blue","red","yellow"))
title("pie1", line=-9)
par(fig=c(0.5,1,0,1),new=TRUE)
p2 <-pie(y, names, col = c("purple", "cyan", "blue", "red", "yellow"))
title("pie2", line=-9)

x = read.csv ("data1.csv")
y = read.csv ("data2.csv")
p3 <-boxplot(x,col=c("green","blue","red"), main = "boxplot1", ylim=c(0,10))
p4 <-boxplot(y,col=c("green","blue","red"), main = "boxplot2", ylim=c(0,10))
```

data1.csv

```
c1 c2 c3
5   7  8
4   5  7
5   5  5
6   5
10
3
```

data2.csv

```
   c1  c2  c3
    5   7  8
    7   4  7
    5   3  5
    6   5
    9
    3
```

Comment: Can you make your example reproducible (use `dput()`)? How exactly would the graph look like? Where do you want the pies to be placed?

Comment: I would like to get two pie charts in the first row and two box plots in the second row.

Answer (score 0):

you can change your plot layout to have multiple plots in it using `par`

```
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
p1
p2
p3
p4
```

Make sure to change it back afterwards:

```
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

Sometimes it will give you an error that the drawing area is too small. In that case you will have to change the outer margins of the individual plots to have less whitespace:

```
par(oma=c(a,b,c,d))
```

where a = left, b = top, c = right, d = bottom.